# Java GSON simple write Json To string

Tags: java, gson

im looking to find out how to make a SIMPLE JSON string using GSON. All of the example require writing the output to a file, I just want to put it into a string.

I want to create a JSON string like this:

```
{"status":"success","error":"FULL ERROR"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what the issue is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CustomBean customBean = new CustomBean();
    customBean.error = "FULL ERROR";
    customBean.status = "success";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(customBean));
}

public static class CustomBean {
    private String status;
    private String error;
}
```

prints

```
{"status":"success","error":"FULL ERROR"}
```

I think you should go through the [`Gson` javadoc.](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

If you don't want the new class, you can do

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.addProperty("status", "success");
object.addProperty("error", "FULL ERROR");
System.out.println(object);
```

which also prints

```
{"status":"success","error":"FULL ERROR"}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without creating a whole new class?